# Laravel unique validation more than one with rule

Tags: php, laravel, web

I have a problem with unique validate on Laravel 9

I want to validate with data not same category_id and not same month, also year

For example i have data:

```js
{
  category_id: 1
  month: 2
  year: 2022
}
```

if i input with

```js
{
  category_id: 1
  month: 3
  year: 2022
}
```

My expectation the data is successfully saved, and if data like this:, its cant saved.

```js
{
  category_id: 1
  month: 3
  year: 2022
}
```

Because of same category_id and month and year.

My Code:

```php
$this->validate($request, [
    'category_id' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('categories')
            ->where('month', '!=', $request->month)
            ->where('year', '!=', $request->year),
        ],
]);
```

How to write this validation on Laravel 9? Thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `'!='` sign.

```php
Rule::unique('categories')
    ->where('month', $request->month)
    ->where('year', $request->year)
```

Comment: Thanks sir, i think the "where" code is like sql normally